# How to convert slider value to textbox

Tags: c#

i'm new in C# and I want to convert value of slider to textbox. One option i found is set binding for text box, but I need send value in event.
I tried some solutions, but not worked.

```
private void sliderName_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        Slider sliderName = sender as Slider;
        TextBox textBoxName = new TextBox();

        textBoxName.Text = sliderName.Value.ToString();

    }
```

Thanks for helping and be patient with me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new `TextBox`, but not positioning it anywhere.

You should have your `TextBox` already on your form, and reference it by the name you gave it at design-time in the IDE. For example, if you just drop a `TextBox` on the form, the IDE will give it a name like `textBox1`, and you use it by that name:

```
private void sliderName_ValueChanged(object sender, 
   RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    // Don't use the same name used on the form if you're
    // declaring a variable here. Use a name that's local to
    // this event.
    Slider slide = sender as Slider;

    // Use the IDE-set name here.
    difficultyBox.Text = slide.Value.ToString();

}
```

Updated to reflect name change based on comment below.

Comment: I'm using same name in IDE and in this procedure.

Comment: No, you're **creating** one in your procedure, which takes the one from the IDE out of scope (it can't be seen). Like I said, *delete* the line that creates the new one in your event handler (the line with `new TextBox()` in it).

Comment: It gave me "nullreferenceexception was unhandled" error. This was my first solution.

Comment: Then you're not using the name properly. But since you posted no other code, it's hard to tell you what you're doing wrong. What **exactly** is the name the IDE gave your `TextBox`? (Click on it, and then look at it's `Properties`.)

Comment: Original code <TextBox Name="difficultyBox" Text="28" />
Slider posuvnik = sender as Slider;
difficultyBox.Text = posuvnik.Value.ToString();

Comment: Thanks for update but still same error and marked difficultyBox.Text line. In other program that i created, almost same code works well.

Comment: Without more code, there's not much more that I can tell you. I have the feeling you have a typo in a name or a scoping conflict (a local variable name that's hiding a form-level name), but I can't see your screen from here. :-) The problem in the code in your question is exactly what I answered here; if you're still having the problem, there's something you're not showing us.

Comment: I found the solution and its simply. Everething was right. But the difficultyBox in form was **after** slider, so textBox cant take his value. Simply, but logical. Again, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach would probably work, except that you are declaring a new TextBox local to this event handler, so you'll never see anything on the screen.

Try setting the .Text property of a TextBox in your form;

```
private void sliderName_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    Slider sliderName = sender as Slider;
    difficultyBox.Text = sliderName.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: If I set some value in form, nothing changed after slider move.
<TextBox Name="difficultyBox" Text="28" />

Comment: Updated code based on this comment - set the .Text property of 'difficultyBox'

Comment: for Slider posuvnik = sender as Slider; difficultyBox.Text = posuvnik.Value.ToString(); i have "nullreferenceexception was unhandled" error

Answer (score 0):

OR an even faster way:

```
private void sliderName_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
 textBox1.Text = ((Slider)sender).value.ToString();
}
```

The only difference between this post, and Ken's Post is that I am casting the sender as a slider while setting the text property of textBox1.

Just showing you different options and a different way of doing the same thing.

Comment: Faster isn't the issue here. The asker is obviously not familiar with C#. Teach basics before you teach optimization. (And you don't actually answer the question asked, and you'd need to prove to me with a profiler that your way is actually **faster** in a way that matters. It might be **shorter** from a typing standpoint, but from a performance standpoint it doesn't matter, and from a readability point for a new programmer it's not as understandable.)

Comment: Sorry I was just showing a different way of doing it. But your right; I should put an explanation.

Comment: @KenWhite Woah man, I by no way meant it was fast in regards to performance, I meant faster to write and read... I definitely wasn't trying to be rude, I was merely providing the poster with a different way of doing something. I realize w/ my lack of explanation in the post it may of seemed that way, but please don't misinterpreted.

Comment: Not faster to read if you're new to C# or programming, and you have to figure out the meaning of what you're reading, which was half of my point. :-) Like I said, knowledge before speed. This poster doesn't understand that creating a new TextBox in the event handler doesn't mean the same as using the one already there on the form, even though they have the same name, so they're learning the basics here. Why complicate things with meaningless shortcuts just to save a few keystrokes?

Comment: @KenWhite Either way sir, I agree with your point. Thanks for pointing that out. I will take your words into consideration the next time I provide an answer.